# Symfony2 using Smarty template system

Tags: templates, symfony, smarty, bundle, twig

Does anyone ever integrate Smarty as template engine as Symfony2 Bundle and is this possible?

Comment: it's most likely possible, but why? Twig is much better in any given field..

Comment: [sure about that?](http://umumble.com/blogs/php/249/)

Comment: @inori In addition to the post linked to by rodneyrehm, have you considered that the OP might have a load of precoded Smarty templates that they don't want to recode? There are always good reasons for needing something different.

Comment: just an FYI as a previous smarty user myself...  Twig seems to be a bit more powerful and easy to utilize than smarty is...  The one think that I like about twig over smarty though is not how easy it is to use or the power associated with it..  But something even of even lesser value.  The size of the twig template engine, isn't quite as bloated as smarty is..  Moving from smarty to Twig is a good idea, and the learning curve isn't that bad really.  You'll do as you wish, but I definitely recommend using twig for your templating...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you seen [SmartyBundle](https://github.com/noiselabs/SmartyBundle) over at github?